# Watermark and Thumbnail - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a script that creates a thumbnail and then will watermark the original image, but the script only creates the thumbnail and skips over the watermarking.

```
 $image = $data['json']->{'file_name'};
   $data['account'] = $account;

   $this->_insertintodb($account, $image);

   //Settings to create thumbnail
   $config['source_image'] = $data['json']->{'file_path'};
   $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
   $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
   $config['width'] = 125;
   $config['height'] = 125;
   $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

   if($this->image_lib->resize()) {
    $prep_thumb = explode('.', $image);
    $thumb = $prep_thumb[0] . '_thumb.' . $prep_thumb[1];
    $this->_moveimage($thumb, $account, TRUE);
   }

   $this->image_lib->clear();

   //Settings to create watermark overlay
   $config = array();
   $config['source_image'] = $data['json']->{'file_path'};
   $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
   $config['wm_overlay_path'] = getcwd() . '/design/overlay_watermark_transparent.png';
   $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
   $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';

   $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

   if(!$this->image_lib->watermark()){
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
   }

   $this->image_lib->clear();
```

Any ideas on why this is not working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If the watermarking isn't working, and you have the required dependencies, you should be getting error messages here:

```
if(!$this->image_lib->watermark()){
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Either those errors can help you more than we can, or we can help you more after you provide us those.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required dependencies? From http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html:

Note: Watermarking is only available using the GD/GD2 library. In addition, even though other libraries are supported, GD is required in order for the script to calculate the image properties. The image processing, however, will be performed with the library you specify.

Looks like you will need to install GD and then include it as your codeigniter image manipulation library.

Comment: It works if you do either one separately, but when you try to do them together it does not

Comment: I don't quite understand what your saying. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you run the functionality of watermarking by itself, it works. If you run the thumbnail functionality by itself, it works. But if you run them together, it doesn't.

Comment: Try putting the code for the watermark before the thumbnail. If its a dependency issue, that might resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

```
/**
 * public function wmimg_thumb($source_image)
 * 
 * Creating water marked - thumb
 * 
 * @param   string  $source_image   : The remaining path to the source   image, after FCPATH.
 * 
 */
function wmimg_thumb($source_image)
{
    if (!file_exists($source_image))
    {
        return "$source_image not exists!";
    }

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 145;
    $config['height'] = 120;
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = FCPATH . $source_image;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if ($this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        // if thumb is created, calculating the name of thumb.
        $thumb_image = str_replace('.', '_thumb.', $source_image);

        $img_config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
        $img_config['wm_overlay_path'] = FCPATH . '/assets/watermark.png';
        $img_config['wm_x_transp'] = 20;
        $img_config['wm_y_transp'] = 10;
        $img_config['wm_opacity'] = 50;
        $img_config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
        $img_config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $img_config['source_image'] = FCPATH . $thumb_image;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($img_config);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();
    }

    if (file_exists(FCPATH . $thumb_image))
    {
        // Up to here, there is 2 images,  $source_image_thumb.extension and $source_image_thumb_thumb.extension. 
        // Deleting the 1st one, which has no watermarking. And renaming the 2nd one, which will be watermarked.
        unlink($thumb_image);
        $wm_thumbname = str_replace('.', '_thumb.', $thumb_image);
        rename(FCPATH . $wm_thumbname, FCPATH . $thumb_image);
    }
}
```